# Returning the terms of a polynomial in clojure

Tags: clojure

I simply need to write a function that will return a list of terms in a polynomial, so for ex: say we have 3x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 + x +10 , it will return an output in the form : [coef variable exponent]

My function so far:

```
(defn terms-of-poly [poly]
    for [x (poly :coefficients)]
    for [y(poly :variables)]
    [x y])
```

Input:

```
(let [poly {:variable "y"
            :coefficients [3 2 1 10]}]
    (vec (terms-of-poly poly)))
```

Output: [[3 "x" 4] [2 "x" 3] [1 "x" 2] [10 "x" 0]]

Comment: shouldn't input coeffs be `[3 2 1 0 10]` then ? Since there the poly is `3x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 + 0x^1 + 10`

Comment: You call the function with `:variable` but you try to read `:variables` from it. Your `for`s lack at least surrounding parens.

Comment: @leetwinski: Since there is an `x` term in the polynomial I'd think the coefficients should be `[3 2 1 1 10]` for `3x^4 + 2x^3 + 1x^2 + 1x^1 + 10x^0`?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica , the op had changed the question (see the edit). the input used to be `3x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 +10`.. so my comment was correct for the initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution could look something like this:

```
(let [poly {:variable "y"
            :coefficients [3 2 1 0 10]}]
  (mapv vector
        (rseq (:coefficients poly))
        (repeat (:variable poly))
        (range)))

;;=> [[10 "y" 0] [0 "y" 1] [1 "y" 2] [2 "y" 3] [3 "y" 4]]
```

it is inverted, but you can reverse it with `rseq` / `reverse`

(notice, i've changed the input, since there is one more member, namely `0x^1`)

more or less the same with list comprehension approach:

```
(let [poly {:variable "y"
            :coefficients [3 2 1 0 10]}]
  (for [[pow coeff] (map-indexed vector (rseq (:coefficients poly)))]
    [coeff (:variable poly) pow]))

;;=> ([10 "y" 0] [0 "y" 1] [1 "y" 2] [2 "y" 3] [3 "y" 4])
```

you can also filter out coeffs with zero multipliers:

```
(let [poly {:variable "y"
            :coefficients [3 2 1 0 10]}]
  (for [[pow coeff] (map-indexed vector (rseq (:coefficients poly)))
        :when (pos? coeff)]
    [coeff (:variable poly) pow]))

;;=> ([10 "y" 0] [1 "y" 2] [2 "y" 3] [3 "y" 4])
```

*update*

if the order is important (though i guess reversed order should be ok, since every element is identified by it's power), you can do the following for example:

```
(defn terms-of-poly [{:keys [variable coefficients]}]
  (map vector
       coefficients
       (repeat variable)
       (range (dec (count coefficients)) -1 -1)))

(let [poly {:variable "y"
            :coefficients [3 2 1 0 10]}]
  (terms-of-poly poly))

;;=> ([3 "y" 4] [2 "y" 3] [1 "y" 2] [0 "y" 1] [10 "y" 0])
```

Comment: So  where could i apply the reverse function to make it produce the correct output? Because it is giving me the output in reverse